# Python/Tkinter - change the "." through the ","

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an application for calculating taxes on revenue, the code itself works normally, but i would like to know if there is a way to change the "." by "," when typing in the entry fields.

Example: 100,50 instead of 100.50

Follow the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
# ---
root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x350')
# ---
l_receita1 = Label(root, text='Receita 1')
l_receita1.place(x=10, y=10)
e_receita1 = Entry(root)
e_receita1.place(x=100, y=10)
l_receita2 = Label(root, text='Receita 2')
l_receita2.place(x=10, y=40)
e_receita2 = Entry(root)
e_receita2.place(x=100, y=40)
# ---
v_result1 = DoubleVar()
l_resRec1 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result1)
l_resRec1.place(x=10, y=100)
v_result2 = DoubleVar()
l_resRec2 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result2)
l_resRec2.place(x=10, y=140)
v_result3 = DoubleVar()
l_resRec3 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result3)
l_resRec3.place(x=10, y=220)
# ---
def calc():
    v_result1.set(round(float(e_receita1.get()) * 8 / 100, 2))
    v_result2.set(round(float(e_receita2.get()) * 12 / 100, 2))
    v_result3.set(round(float(v_result1.get() + v_result2.get()), 2))

    e_receita1.delete(0, END)
    e_receita2.delete(0, END)
# ---
bt = Button(root, text='Calcular', command=calc)
bt.place(x=10, y=180)
# ---
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Plz, make a reproducible and minimal example, instead of having ppl to read your entire code and figure out what you are talking about. (See section "Help others reproduce the problem" in [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the "." character and have it insert a "," instead. Use `return "break"` to prevent the default behavior.

```
def replace_period(event):
    event.widget.insert("insert", ",")
    return "break"

e_receita1.bind("<.>", replace_period)  # or "<period>"
```

Comment: You've been at this too long Bryan, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: continues with the same error.  ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100,50'

Answer (score 0):

Using a `bind`, and in the callback function replacing "." with ",":

```
from tkinter import *
# ---
root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x350')
# ---
def callback(e):
    """Function to change "." to "," while typing in an entry"""
    val = e.widget.get()

    # If statement avoids unnecessary delete/insert calls
    if "." in val:
        e.widget.delete(0, "end")
        e.widget.insert(0, val.replace(".", ","))

l_receita1 = Label(root, text='Receita 1')
l_receita1.place(x=10, y=10)
e_receita1 = Entry(root)
e_receita1.bind('<KeyRelease>', callback) # Bind the key release
e_receita1.place(x=100, y=10)
l_receita2 = Label(root, text='Receita 2')
l_receita2.place(x=10, y=40)
e_receita2 = Entry(root)
e_receita2.bind('<KeyRelease>', callback) # Bind the key release
e_receita2.place(x=100, y=40)
# ---
v_result1 = DoubleVar()
l_resRec1 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result1)
l_resRec1.place(x=10, y=100)
v_result2 = DoubleVar()
l_resRec2 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result2)
l_resRec2.place(x=10, y=140)
v_result3 = DoubleVar()
l_resRec3 = Label(root, textvariable=v_result3)
l_resRec3.place(x=10, y=220)
# ---
def calc():
    v_result1.set(round(float(e_receita1.get().replace(",", ".")) * 8 / 100, 2))
    v_result2.set(round(float(e_receita2.get().replace(",", ".")) * 12 / 100, 2))
    v_result3.set(round(float(v_result1.get() + v_result2.get()), 2))

    e_receita1.delete(0, END)
    e_receita2.delete(0, END)
# ---
bt = Button(root, text='Calcular', command=calc)
bt.place(x=10, y=180)
# ---
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: he returned the following error to me: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100,50'

Comment: Since python can only interpret floats that have a "." you're going to have to switch the "," back to a "." for it to be a number and not a string. I updated the code.